# tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath difficult to receive event

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7

I have a customised cell that need to receive the swipe event so it can show the delete button on the right side.

It is an iPad application.

The problem is that it is very difficult to receive the event. Just when swiping very fast that the delegate is called. In other cells in my project this is not happening.

I tried to remove the views inside the cell and it is still difficult.

Also tried to just return yes on the canEditRowAtIndexPath delegate instead of all my logic inside. But the problem is that the delegate is not called.

I also checked if there is any gesture recogniser that is confusing the default swipe recog.

Anyone has a tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem using SWRevealViewController, so I canceled the swipe touch using this delegate

```
- (BOOL)revealControllerPanGestureShouldBegin:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController
{
    return NO;
}
```